# Questions regarding PHPUnit mock feature

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

Can someone provide me a reference to a good PHPUnit mock guide? The one in the [official documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/mock-objects.html) doesn't seem to be detailed enough. I am trying to study PHPUnit by reading the source code, but I am not familiar with the term matcher, invocation mocker, stub return, etc.

I need to know about the following:

***1)*** How to expect multiple calls to a mock object's method, but each return a different sets of value?

```
$tableMock->expects($this->exactly(2))
    ->method('find')
    ->will($this->returnValue(2)); // I need the second call to return different value
```

***2)*** How to expect a call to a mock object's method with multiple parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*Note: All code samples from the sites linked, follow the links for more thorough explanations.*]

### Return Different Values

The (current) PHPUnit documentation suggests [using a callback](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest4.php) or [`onConsecutiveCalls()`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php):

```
$stub->expects($this->any())
      ->method('doSomething')
      ->will($this->returnCallback('str_rot13'));

$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('doSomething')
     ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls(2, 3, 5, 7));
```

### Expect Multiple Parameters

`with()` may contain [multiple parameters](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.MultiParameterTest.php):

```
$observer->expects($this->once())
         ->method('reportError')
         ->with($this->greaterThan(0),
                $this->stringContains('Something'),
                $this->anything());
```

### Test Multiple Calls

Although not ask, on a related topic (and not in the PHPUnit documentation that I can find), you can use `at()` to [set expectations for multiple calls to a method](http://www.kreamer.org/phpunit-cookbook/1.0/mocks/set-mock-expectations-for-multiple-calls-to-a-function):

```
$inputFile->expects($this->at(0))
          ->method('read')
          ->will($this->returnValue("3 4"));
$inputFile->expects($this->at(1))
          ->method('read')
          ->will($this->returnValue("4 6"));
$inputFile->expects($this->at(2))
          ->method('read')
          ->will($this->returnValue(NULL));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always create your own mock classes (you don't need to use the built in Mock object):

```
class tableMock extends Table {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function find($id) {
        return $id;
    }
}

$tableMock = new tableMock();

//Do your testing here...
```

If you want to fail the test from inside of the Mock, just throw an exception...